# geolocation accuracy with ios

Tags: android, ios, cordova, geolocation, geocoding

I am working on an app that will leverage the geolocation to update the location of either vehicles or other "parked" items within a specific area, either large parking lot or other outdoor facility.
 I can build this app either as an HTML5 app and use phonegap to distribute it to both ios and android or I can build as an ios native app.
 My first question is in regards to which is more accurate the native ios geolocation services or the HTML5 (I am assuming browser) capabilities?
 My second question is, in order for me to get the most accurate reading, will I need to know the coordinates for the boundries of the area in question and then calculate position based on the users location in regards to the boundries? (is this triangulation?)
 Obviously I have never done anything like this so I am looking for guidance and logic not code. Also I really need to know how to get the greatest accuracy as I have mocked up this app using HTML5 and phone gap and I am not very happy with the level of accuracy.
 Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The level of accuracy available to either a native app or HTML5 app is the same. It depends on which mechanism on the device you use to determine position as to the accuracy delivered to your app. The most accurate position that can be obtained is via GPS, as opposed to phone signal triangulation or a WiFi connection. The accuracy of the GPS position you receive isn't related to the mechanism you use to implement your app (native or HTML5) but a function of the hardware that the device is running (i.e. the GPS receiver), the geographical location, weather conditions, etc.

In answer to your second question, there's nothing you need to (or can) do in terms of implementing your app to improve the accuracy of the GPS position you receive. You can, however, choose to ignore readings which are outside of minimum level of accuracy (the data returned in the geolocation message contains an estimated level of accuracy).

I've implemented an app using Phonegap and during testing found the average accuracy of the GPS positions returned to be within 2 to 6 metres depending on the device.

If you're using Phonegap, make sure to use the "enableHighAccuracy" parameter when requesting a position to make sure a GPS fix is requested from the underlying OS. Beware though that even if you do this, inaccurate positions can still be returned so it's best to set up a filter to reject any that are too inaccurate.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I had already tried everything you have suggested, but the best I accuracy I can achieve is 10 meters!! Does this sound right? I am using the watchPosition method, should I be doing anything else or do I have to be satisfied with 10 meters?

Comment: 10 metres accuracy is not unusual for GPS depending on your device, location, etc. If possible try using a different device in the same location and compare the results.

Comment: I noticed difference between the HTC android and iPhone 4S. I tested the same html5 script with watchLocation and the accuracy on the HTC stays in 3 meters while the iPhone begins with 5 meters and after 1 minute or so it climbs to 100 till 1000 meters and never came back...